# ¿Cómo puedo establecer inputs con valor 0 en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero mostrar las calificaciones de los estudiantes.

Esto es el resultado que tengo:

[image: Foto en el navegador]

... pero quisiera que quede de la siguiente manera:

[image: Foto creada en paint]

Esta es mi tabla de la base de datos:

> |id_nota|rut_alumno|id_materia|nota|

¿Cómo puedo dejar a los estudiantes que no tienen notas con un valor de `input` de `0`?

**Prueba.php**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Rut</td>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Apellido</td>
      <td>Notas</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
    if (!$connect) {
      die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("liceo");
    $results = mysql_query(
     "SELECT rut, nombre, apellido FROM alumnos"
    ) or die(mysql_error);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($results)) {
      $rut = $row->rut;

      $results2 = mysql_query(
       "SELECT nota FROM notas WHERE rut_alumno = '$rut' LIMIT 2"
      );
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?=$row->rut?></td>
        <td><?=$row->nombre?></td>
        <td><?=$row->apellido?></td>
        <td>
          <?php
          while($nota = mysql_fetch_object($results2)):
          ?>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="pin"
              maxlength="2"
              size="2"
              value="<?=$nota->nota?>"
            >
          <?php
          endwhile;
          ?>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <?php
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar recomendar Leer esto [¿Cómo evitar la Inyección SQL ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Para una posible solución hay que tomar en cuenta que :

- Puede que No existan notas para un determinado alumno
- Puede que Solo exista Una nota para un determinado alumno
- Puede que existan Dos notas para un determinado alumno

Esto se puede validar desde `PHP` con una variable Auxiliar, el código quedaría algo así. *(la explicación está dentro de los comentarios)* se hizo el cambio de extensión `mysql` a `mysqli` aunque lo más óptimo sería usar `PDO`

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>Nombre</td>
<td>Notas</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","liceo");
if (!$connect) {
die(mysqli_error());
}
$results = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT rut, nombre, apellido FROM alumnos");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($results)) {
$rut = $row->rut;
$boo = 0; /* Iniciamos la Variable Auxiliar
          que indicará cuantas notas se imprimió  por cada Alumno  */
$results2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT nota FROM notas WHERE rut_alumno = '$rut' LIMIT 2");
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$row->rut?></td>
<td><?=$row->nombre?></td>
<td><?=$row->apellido?></td>
<td>
<?php
while($nota = mysqli_fetch_object($results2)):
?>
 <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="<?=$nota->nota?>">
<?php
    $boo +=1;/* Incrementamos después de Imprimir la nota del Alumno*/
endwhile;
/* Si la variable es menor a 2 , es decir no se imprimieron las 2 notas respectivas*/
if($boo<2){ 
    /* Imprimimos  inputs de value 0 hasta que sea < 2 , dado que si el
    el valor de $boo es 1 o 0 , primero se realizará el echo y luego el incremento
    Sí $boo es 0 -> Iteración 0 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 1
                    Iteración 1 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 2
                    Termina el for dado que 2 no es menor que 2
    Sí $boo es 1 -> Iteración 0 - Imprime el input - Incrementa $boo -> $boo = 2
                    Termina el For dado que 2 no es menor que 2
     */
    for (; $boo < 2; $boo++) { 
        echo '<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="0">';
    }
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- ----------------------------
```

-- Table structure for balance

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `balance`;
CREATE TABLE `balance` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `debito` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `credito` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  **`status` int(2) DEFAULT '0',**
  **`pendiente` int(2) DEFAULT '0',**
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=154 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score 0):

1) Tener la etiqueta:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

2) Insertar campo donde se define por defecto que valor tendra este campo -> value=""

```
<input type="text" value="">
```

3) Preparar sentencia de php que permita decir que si el valor de la nota es igual a 0, entonces imprime 0. pero si no es igual a 0 Entonces imprime mi valor de la nota.

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if ($variable_que_tiene_la_nota == 0) {echo 0; } else { echo $variable_que_tiene_la_nota; }; ?>">
```